# How do I perform a join in Laravel 5 with a `where` clause?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

I have a table, `offers`, with purchases which has an `id` for the purchased item. The item is stored in another table, `items`. In response to a `GET` request, I want to return the full item object with purchases. How do I go about doing this?

```
public function getBuys(Request $request)
{
    $usr_id = $request->input('usrid');

    $buys = Offer::where('buyer_id', '=', $usr_id)->get();
    return response()->json($buys);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are getting all the offer(purchases) made by a user correct? If you want to get a specific item with all offers (assuming you have realtionship set in your item model):

```
$item = Item::->with('offers')->find($itemId);
```

EDIT
If you have this relation in you Offer model:

```
public function item()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Item');
}
```

you can just do this:

```
$buys = Offer::with('item')->where('buyer_id', '=', $usr_id)->get();
```

Comment: I want to return all the `buys` (offers) with their respective items, instead of just the `item_id` that I get today.

Comment: I get this error: `FatalErrorException in /var/www/html/laravel5/vendor/compiled.php line 9578: Class 'Game' not found`

Comment: I have a `Game.php` model in my `app` folder. It is defined as such:
  <?php namespace App;

  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

  class Game extends Model
  {
      //
  }

And the `Offer.php` model is defined as:

  <?php namespace App;

  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

  class Offer extends Model
  {

   public function game() {
    return $this->hasOne('Game');
   }

  }

And this is what I am doing in my controller:
  $buys = Offer::with('game')->where('buyer_id', '=', $usr_id)->get();

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified, I did dump autoload. Still the same error.

Comment: Actually, it has changed to `FatalErrorException in Model.php line 750: Class 'App/Game' not found`

Comment: try `return $this->hasOne('App\Game');` in your relation

Comment: Thanks a LOT! My bad on the backslash! Coming from iOS.. backslashes just do not register in my head!